# Is it possible to suspend already shown, and new notifications for an amount of time? Or cancel them all and revive them after finishing an activity?

Tags: android, notifications, push

So I am developing a social game, where you have a certain ammount of time to do a task. Since it is social, you can chat with the other player.

Everytime you receive a chat message you will also get a notification and upon clicking on it you are redirected to the chat screen with him. Right now this is working good.

What I don't want is, that the user will receive a chat notification while he actually is playing on the PlayActivity.

It would be also good, if already shown notification could be ignored or suspended to a later time while he is on the PlayActivity.

Is this accomplishable?

A different approach could be to cancel all already shown notifications and put the BroadcastReceiver to sleep and revive all notifications and the BroadcastReceiver after the PlayActivity is done?

Not possible either?

Could the app at least ask before leaving the activity? that way i could warn him and if he still leaves, the game could be valued against him.

What I do right now is just a workaround, I make the PlayActivity full screen and check if the focus has changed e.g. if he is dragging down the status bar / notification area. But this is just a hack, something I would really like to do away with it.

As you see, I am not really sure what the right approach here could be. What would a pro Android software developer do in my case?

Thanks in advance!

Right now I am handling notifications by extending a BroadcastReceiver. Code is appended at the end, if you need other parts of my code, let me know!

```
public class PushBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            try 
            {

              JSONObject json = 
                  new JSONObject(
                          intent.getExtras()
                             .getString("KEY"));


              notify(context,intent,json);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                L.debug(App.TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private void notify(Context ctx, Intent i, JSONObject dataObject) throws JSONException
        {

              NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) 
                      ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

              boolean createNotification = false;

              PendingIntent pi = null;

              int gameId = 0;

          // chat
              if (dataObject.getString("KEY_CHAT").equals("VALUE_CHAT")) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ChatActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("opponentUsername", dataObject.getString(PARSE_JSON_OPPONENT_USERNAME_KEY));
                  intent.putExtra("gameId", dataObject.getString(PARSE_JSON_GAME_ID_KEY));

                  pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                  gameId = Integer.parseInt(dataObject.getString(PARSE_JSON_GAME_ID_KEY));              

                  createNotification = true;

              // game
              } else if (dataObject.getString("KEY_GAME").equals("VALUE_GAME")) {


                  Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, SS6RunningGameActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("gameId", dataObject.getString(PARSE_JSON_GAME_ID_KEY));
                  gameId = Integer.parseInt(dataObject.getString(PARSE_JSON_GAME_ID_KEY));

                  pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                  createNotification = true;

              } 

              if (createNotification) {


                  Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                          + ctx.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.push_notif); 

                  int icon = R.drawable.icon_notification_android;

                  String tickerText = 
                          dataObject.getString("TEXT");

                  Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)

                                .setContentTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .setContentText(tickerText)
                                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                                .setContentIntent(pi)
                                .setSound(sound)
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(tickerText))                    
                                .build();


                  nm.notify(gameId, mNotification);               

              }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many approaches to this.

One of the simplest would be the following:

Use `SharedPreferences`. Add a `boolean` value to indicate that `PlayActivity` is currently running.

In `onCreate(Bundle)` of `PlayActivity`, do the following:

```
// Initialization
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF_FILE_NAME", 0);
Editor edit = preferences.edit();

// Here, "PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING" is the `key` and `true` is the value
// We are saying that `PlayActivity` is running
edit.putBoolean("PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING", true);
edit.commit();
```

Now, in `onPause()` of `PlayActivity`, set this `boolean` to `false` - indicating that we are about to leave `PlayActivity`:

```
// Initialization
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF_FILE_NAME", 0);
Editor edit = preferences.edit();

// Here, "PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING" is the `key` and `false` is the value
// We are saying that `PlayActivity` is not running anymore
edit.putBoolean("PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING", false);
edit.commit();
```

Rest is quite simple.

In `PushBroadcastReceiver`, open `SharedPreferences` and check for the value assigned to key `PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING`. If this value is `false`, continue posting the notifications. Else, collect them for later.

```
public class PushBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
                                                    "MY_PREF_FILE_NAME", 0);

        // Retrieve the value stored for key "PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING"
        // The second argument `false` is the default value
        // in case the key does not exist - this is logically sound
        boolean playActivityIsRunning = preferences.getBoolean(
                                                    "PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING", false)
        // PlayActivity is running
        if (playActivityIsRunning) {

            // store JSON objects somewhere and deal with them later

        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("KEY"));
                notify(context,intent,json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                L.debug(App.TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void notify(Context ctx, Intent i, JSONObject dataObject) throws JSONException {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

You *will* need to find a way to post the pending notifications. One solution for this is to send a separate broadcast to another `BroadcastReceiver` in `onPause()` of `PlayActivity`. But this could be problematic because `onPause()` is called even when the user is changing orientation. Perhaps this `BroadcastReceiver` can start working after a `1 second` delay? This would be sufficient time for the activity to be recreated - and the value of `PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING` reset (since `onCreate(Bundle)` of `PlayActivity` will be called again).

So, the flow would be:

- `onPause` is called
- set the value to `false` in `SharedPreferences`
- send the broadcast to deal with pending notifications
- place the code of `BroadcastReceiver` inside a `Runnable`. Post this `Runnable` with a `1 second` delay using a `Handler`.
- inside the `BroadcastReciever` => check value of `PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING` in `SharedPreferences` <= this will be done *after* 1 second. If the user only changed screen orientation, the value of `PLAY_ACTIVITY_IS_RUNNING` would be `true`. Otherwise, if the user is navigated away from `PlayActivity`, the value would be `false`.

Comment: sounds straightforward, what about the notifications that are already shown?

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas Is `dataObject.getString(PARSE_JSON_GAME_ID_KEY)` unique for each notification? Or is it the same `int` passed to each JSONObject?

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas Then you will need to store these `ids`. When its time to cancel these notifications, use `mNotificationManager.cancel(id)`. The way I have implemented this is: whenever a notification is posted, I save all relevant information about the notification (in a database table). So if I wanted to recreate the notification, I can(for example, post boot). When the user clicks/dismisses the notification, I remove the associated entry from the database. This way, I always know which notifications are being displayed. And should the need arise, I can cancel/re-post them.

Comment: interesting idea, how do you delete the notifications from the database which the user swipes away?

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas You are already using the click intent ==> `setContentIntent(pi)` - this is fired when the user clicks the notification. In addition to this, I also attach a delete intent using `setDeleteIntent(Intent)`. The intent sends a `delete` broadcast => my clean-up `BroadcastReceiver` steps in, and deletes an entry from the database. The `id` of the entry is included in the `deleteIntent`. This `deleteIntent` is fired when the user swipes the notification.

Comment: last question, is there a reason you would use getSharedPreferences over a static variable to monitor if the playactivity is running?

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas It's the android way. In your case, static variables should be fine - say `0` for when `PlayActivity` is not running and `1` for when it is. The problem with using static variables in android is - when the activity is destroyed, they will be initialized. So, a static `String` to pass data will get you in trouble. But, like I said, in this case it should work fine - an `int`, even if initialized (to `0`, after `PlayActivity` is no more) _will_ indicate correctly.